# Quick Return Pattern for FAB and ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a simple ListView inside a ViewPager and a Floating Action Bar at the bottom right corner of the screen.

I want to implement the Quick Return pattern to it so that when I scroll the ListView the FAB goes down the screen and comes up on opposite scroll.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
list.setAdapter(new QuickReturnAdapter(adapter));
            quickReturnAttacher = QuickReturnAttacher.forView(list);
            quickReturnAttacher.addTargetView(floatMenu, AbsListViewScrollTarget.POSITION_BOTTOM, dpToPx(context, 400));

            if (quickReturnAttacher instanceof AbsListViewQuickReturnAttacher) {
                // This is the correct way to register an OnScrollListener.
                // You have to add it on the QuickReturnAttacher, instead
                // of on the viewGroup directly.
                final AbsListViewQuickReturnAttacher attacher = (AbsListViewQuickReturnAttacher) quickReturnAttacher;
                attacher.addOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                    }
                });
            }
```

Then I am using quickReturnAttacher.setOnItemClickListener and this ain't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an open source library for this feature.
https://github.com/felipecsl/QuickReturn

Try this:

```
    final AbsListViewQuickReturnAttacher attacher =   (AbsListViewQuickReturnAttacher) quickReturnAttacher;
    attacher.addOnScrollListener(this);
    attacher.setOnItemClickListener(this);

});
```

For me this is working, the position passed in the callback is correct.
You have to register your click listener to the attacher, not to the list.

How do you cannot find the method `setOnItemClickListener` in the class `AbsListViewQuickReturnAttacher`?

Comment: Yes I have already tried this library. You can check my problem in the latest issue. When ever I use this library, and click on an item in the listview the lower item gets selected.

Comment: You have to add your onClickListener to the attacher. In the callback you will get the right position  (`attacher.setOnItemClickListener`)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Can you elaborate a bit more please? I have added some code in the question too.

Comment: There is no method like setOnItemClickListener in the attacher class. How come it is working for you? Can you please post the full code.

Comment: @Aritra QuickReturnAttacher != AbsListViewQuickReturnAttacher, latter one has the mentioned method

Comment: Yes, this absolutely solved the problem, but partially. I am using MULTI_CHOIDE_MODE for CAB. Now, when in CAB, it again selects wrong items.

Comment: In MULTI_CHOICE_MODE you have to to substract 1 from the position in the callback (onItemCheckedStateChanged), because the implementation adds a headerview to the list.

Comment: Yes, that's what I actually did and it worked. But I didn't know the real reason behind it. Thanks a lot for it. I have also subtracted 1 in onItemClick also and it worked. :-)

Comment: The reason is that the library adds a headerview to the list, so the first item is "reserved" for the QuickReturn implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for Quick Return Pattern for ListViews:

```
yourListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
         @SuppressLint("NewApi")
         @Override
         public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int scrollOffset = 0;
            float transitionY;

            if (firstVisibleItem > 0) {
               scrollOffset += headerHeight;
               if (firstVisibleItem > 1) {
                  scrollOffset += (firstVisibleItem - 1) * cellHeight;
               }
            }

            if (yourListView.getChildCount() > 0) {
               scrollOffset += -yourListView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
               scrollOffset = -scrollOffset;
            }

            float scrollDelta = scrollOffset - prevOffset;
            float nextY = mQuickReturnView.getY() + scrollDelta;

            if (nextY < minRawY) {
               transitionY = minRawY;
            }
            else if (nextY > qReturnDelta) {
               transitionY = qReturnDelta;
            }
            else {
               transitionY = nextY;
            }

            mQuickReturnView.setY(transitionY);
            prevOffset = scrollOffset;
         }

         @Override
         public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
         }
      });
```